# Why is BigCommerce API POST request not getting through?

Tags: bigcommerce

I've been for months trying to get more complex type of POST requests to go through and somehow I've never been able. Those like creating a product or a brand are always easy, but when u get to creating complex-rules and modifiers your API seems to close all the doors...

I'm trying to create a **Complex-Rule for changing the image when two or more option values are selected**. I tried every possible combination of what I think could be the needed values and nothing. Is it possible that I'm misinterpreting what the **array of inline_response_200_19_conditions** are and how to use them?

[image]

This is the response I get every time...

Any help here would be very much appreciated and would save me from doing more than **25.000 combinations** and image uploads by hand... :/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I too have the same issue. Have you gotten this to work?

Comment: Hey! Yeah! Someone answered me on the bigcommerce forum actually! Apparently there's an issue there with that endpoint and they will fix it. In the meantime you need to use the v2 API for that. See it in full here:
https://forum.bigcommerce.com/s/feed/0D51B000046Mxsx?t=1516886861226